# Is there any valid way to do CSS for <title> tag?

Tags: css, title

I'm developing a site with Bānglā title, and the site title is also in Bānglā. The embedded Bānglā fonts are working on-site (`<body>`), except the `<title>`. It's showing scrambled texts. If I can put some CSS to work on the `<title>` it'd be surely OK.

I tried:

```
head title{
  font-family: 'Bangla Font','English Font',serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

But nothing happened. I did the second property to take the effect, if that actually affect. But nothing...

#### EDIT

After the comments, yap, my `<head>` is echoing `charset=UTF-8`, it's a WordPress site. The browser was FireFox. The same FireFox in my home, where the browser settings are set for Bengali scripts with UTF-8, it's OK. But in my office PC, it's not working - I din't check the browser's Bengali scripts settings there, but probably that's set too. Using FF 20.0 at home PC, and [if I recall correctly] FF 25.0 in office PC.

Comment: Which browser/OS? What's the declared encoding of your document? What encoding is your document actually saved in? Can you show your actual HTML code, including the title? Can you describe "scrambled" a bit better? You can't style a `<title>` -- that's not handled by the rendering engine -- but you might be able to have the title appear okay if you get the encoding right.

Comment: I don't think you can apply styles to <head> elements. That's not their purpose. <head> element holds data about your page. <title> element is displayed in the browser's tab and the tab is part of the browser itself, you cannot modify browser's elements. Most likely Bangla language is not supported in the browser program itself (Bangla character enconding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @code-zoop said: You should set your [charset](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.2.2) to utf8

You can do this with a meta element:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
```

Place that anywhere in your webpage(preferable in the header) and your title should be rendered normally.

---

As for the css for your title, **no that's not possible.**

`"The TITLE element is not considered part of the flow of text"`

Thus not support the css markup. You can use [HTML enitities](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) in your title for decoration.

Source : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the title is shown in the browser title bar and NOT on the page where styles get applied, so even if you set style on title tag, it wont have any effect on the title shown in the browser title bar

Comment: This is not true. One can declare: head, title { display:block;} and then title is shown on the document.

Comment: @zvona  What i meant here, is that it wont have any effect on the title shown in the browser title bar. I edited - and clarified my answer now. Thanks for the hint!